# Stability Index for Fuzzy c Means Clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, validation, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I am looking for a stability measure/index for Fuzzy C Means Clustering in R. Can anyone direct me to a package or a code in R? I am not looking for internal indices, only stability measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so familiar with fuzzy clustering, going through the literature it seems like Dunn’s partition coefficient is often used, and in the implementation in `cluster` for another similar fuzzy cluster algorithm `fanny`, it writes

> coeff: Dunn’s partition coefficient F(k) of the clustering, where k is
>   the number of clusters. F(k) is the sum of all squared membership
>   coefficients, divided by the number of observations. Its value is
>   between 1/k and 1. The normalized form of the coefficient is also
>   given. It is defined as (F(k) − 1/k)/(1−1/k), and ranges between 0 and
>   1. A low value of Dunn’s coefficient indicates a very fuzzy clustering, whereas a value close to 1 indicates a nearcrisp
>   clustering

We can try that using iris with `cmeans()` from `e1071` and also compare it with `fanny()`:

```
Fn = function(c1){
n = nrow(c1$membership)
k = length(unique(clus$cluster))
nu = sum(c1$membership^2)/n
c(nu,(k*nu - 1)/(k-1))
}

library(e1071)
library(cluster)
library(mclust)

data <-scale(iris[,-5])

dunn_fanny = sapply(2:6,function(i)Fn(fanny(data,i,maxit=1000)))
dunn_cmeans = sapply(2:6,function(i)Fn(cmeans(data,i)))

plot(2:6,dunn_fanny[2,],"l",ylim=c(0,1),col="blue",
ylab="Normalized partition coefficient",xlab="no of clusters")
lines(2:6,dunn_cmeans[2,],"l",ylim=c(0,1),col="brown")
legend("topright",fill=c("blue","brown"),c("fanny","cmeans"))
```

[image]

Really depends on your data, whether this works or not.. And my guess is like the same for all clustering methods, there's no good way to determine number of clusters. I think for comparing methods, it might be ok.

Comment: @ StupidWolf thank you so much.